# How to compare array elements that are not parrallel while looping through the lines of a text file?

Tags: java, arrays

I am stuck with this logic. I have two text files that the program reads, but I cannot get it to compare each other the following way:

First text file looks like this:

```
1,01/04/14,apo,14:47:53,
2,01/04/14,apo,14:48:08,
3,01/04/14,apo,14:48:25,
7,01/04/14,apo,14:53:50,
```

Second text file looks like this:

```
1,01/04/14,apo,14:47:53,
2,01/04/14,apo,14:48:08,
4,01/04/14,apo,14:48:25,
7,01/04/14,apo,14:53:50,
```

Each line of text from each file is stored in an array. I want to grab from the first line of the first text file, the first array of the first line which is "1" and compare that to every first array element of each line in the second file. Then grab the first array element of the second line of the first text file which is "2" and compare that to the first array element of each line on the second text file.

This is what I have done so far:

```
while ( (tkp = tkpbr.readLine()) != null && (tkn = tknbr.readLine()) != null){
            tkparray = tkp.split(",");
            int c = 0;
            for(String s : tkparray){
                //System.out.println("values[" + c + "] = " + s);
                c++;
            }

            tknarray = tkn.split(",");
            int a = 0;
            for(String s : tknarray){
                //System.out.println("values[" + a + "] = " + s);
                a++;
            }

            if(tkparray[0].contentEquals(tknarray[0])){
                System.out.println(tkparray[0]+"\t"+tknarray[0]);
            }


            }
```

This works, but if the array elements are not equal or if the text files look like below it won`t work:

First text file looks like this:

```
1,01/04/14,apo,14:47:53,
2,01/04/14,apo,14:48:08,
3,01/04/14,apo,14:48:25,
7,01/04/14,apo,14:53:50,
```

Second text file looks like this:

```
3,01/04/14,apo,14:47:53,
7,01/04/14,apo,14:48:08,
1,01/04/14,apo,14:48:25,
2,01/04/14,apo,14:53:50,
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, what about sorting the array (while loading it from the file) by the first element of the array (the first element from the line read)? Then it's easier to compare the arrays created from the two files.

Comment: I agree with @jedison, sorting tends to improve efficiency as well

Comment: Yes, @MarshallTigerus, another good point. thanks

Comment: Ok. I see what you are saying. How would I go about sorting them. I tried using Arrays.sort(); and it did not work. @jedison

Comment: Yeah, `Arrays.sort()`is going to sort the elements of the array, not sort the arrays. To do that, you need to add each line (tkparray, tknarray) into another array, then run sort that "file array".

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it.

One is to create a class that modelizes each lines of both files. Assuming each line is unique in a file (looking at the first number), store each lines in two Set and check for equality at the end.

```
class Date {
   private long id;
   private Date date;
   private String desc;

   //constructor and all stuff
   //don't forget to override equals and hashcode
}

Set<Data> datasFileOne = new HashSet<>();
Set<Data> datasFileTwo = new HashSet<>();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

while ((tkp = tkpbr.readLine()) != null && (tkn = tknbr.readLine()) != null){
        tkparray = tkp.split(",");
        datasFileOne.add(new Data(Long.parseLong(tkparray[0]), 
                                    sdf.format(tkparray[1]+" "+tkparray[3]),
                                    tkparray[2]);

        //do the same thing for setFileTwo
}

boolean filesEquals = datasFileOne.equals(datasFileTwo);
```

If you don't care about storing those values in a POJO, you could use `Files.readAllLines` (if you're using Java 7).

```
Path p1 = //Path to file one
Path p2 = //Path to file two    
Charset cs = //encoding of the files

List<String> datasFileOne = Files.readAllLines(p1, cs);
List<String> datasFileTwo = Files.readAllLines(p2, cs);

if(datasFileOne.size() == datasFileTwo.size()){
   Collections.sort(datasFileOne);
   Collections.sort(datasFileTwo);
   if(datasFileOne.equals(datasFileTwo)){
      //same content
   }
} else { 
      //not same content
}
```